# Need to validate both files are present, before moving to another folder

Tags: windows, pdf

I want to check to see if the matching file exists, before moving the files to another folder.

Example:  If 9999999.PDF exists in folder C:\Miraca\Results   and
 9999999.hl7 exists, then move to Z:\

If 9999999.PDF exists in folder C:\Miraca\Results  but
  9999999.hl7 does not exist, go to next PDF message.

Comment: Have you tried to write a script say in [Python](http://www.python.org)? It has the tools you can use to make what you want.

Comment: I assume you are on windows based on your paths but please remember to include your OS when asking. What language do you want to do this in? Do you know any scripting languages? Are you asking for existing software?

Answer (score 0):

Here is BATH (.bat) script to do the task:

> @echo off
>  set path1=C:\Miraca\Results\
>  set
>   path2=C:\Miraca\Results\
>  set file1=9999999.PDF
>  set
>   file2=9999999.hl7
>
> if exist "%path1%%file1%" (
>  if exist "%path2%%file2%" (
>  goto
>   FileBoth
>  ) else (
>  goto File1
>  )
>  ) else (
>  if exist
>   "%path2%%file2%" (
>  goto File2
>  ) else (
>  goto FileNone
>   )
>  )
>
> :FileBoth
>  echo Both of files does exist.
>  goto end
>
> :FileNone
>  echo Both of files does NOT exist.
>  goto end
>
> :File1
>  echo %file1% at %path1% exist.
>  goto end
>
> :File2
>  echo %file2% at %path2% exist.
>  goto end
>
> :end
>  pause
>  exit